# Is Galaxy S5 capable to receive IR signals

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm thinking to buy a Galaxy S5, I have a question.

The Galaxy S4 can transmit IR signals, but not receive them.

I want to make my own remotes. Does Galaxy S5 (NOT mini) have an IR blaster (receiver, not transmitter)? I cannot find info, I wait for answers to this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is the answer to your question. I'm not sure but according to this link it can't. http://www.tamatalk.com/IB/topic/190144-a-way-to-get-galaxy-s5-to-send-files-via-ir/

Answer (score 1):

I have a galaxy s5 g900f variant. It comes with a stock app peel smart remote which can basically be used to control most devices that are IR enabled. The IR blaster is located at the top left of the phone as a small black dot like shape which is easily noticeable. [image: Adding a new device]
[image: Adding a new device -2]
[image: Functional Remote -1]
[image: Functional Remote -2]

Comment: I know Galaxy S5 has an IR Blaster, my question is "Is Galaxy S5 CAPABLE to **RECEIVE** IR signals?"

Comment: The IR Blaster can only send signals not receive any. Of which it can mostly control IR remote controlled devices like TV Audio systems and small scale Entertainment Systems.